# SP 2013 > How to create Local Terms for a site collection?

Tags: term-store

I went to site collection's site setting > term store management > but I dont see a way to create local term set group for this given site collection

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Just had to make sure one of option is checked via central admin for Managed Metadata service app

https://jerryyasir.wordpress.com/2012/10/10/managed-metadata-service-application-the-default-term-store-for-this-site-cannot-be-identified/

Thanks